# PHP - how do you sanitize your contact forms?

Tags: php, security

Has anyone come across a bulletproof function/class (homemade or native) for securing contact forms?

Answer (score 0):

See:

**[Secure Your Forms With Form Keys](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/secure-your-forms-with-form-keys/)**

Even better, employ:

**[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)**

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
>   HTML filter library written in PHP.
>   HTML Purifier will not only remove all
>   malicious code (better known as XSS)
>   with a thoroughly audited, secure yet
>   permissive whitelist, it will also
>   make sure your documents are standards
>   compliant, something only achievable
>   with a comprehensive knowledge of
>   W3C's specifications. Tired of using
>   BBCode due to the current landscape of
>   deficient or insecure HTML filters?
>   Have a WYSIWYG editor but never been
>   able to use it? Looking for
>   high-quality, standards-compliant,
>   open-source components for that
>   application you're building? HTML
>   Purifier is for you!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the OWASP [Enterprise Security API](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API#tab=PHP) it is a collection of accessors that [filter user input](http://owasp-esapi-php.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/index.html) based on the type of data it *should* be. Another complimentary security layer is an Web Application Firewall (WAF) such as [PHP-IDS](http://php-ids.org/) or [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/). A WAF will prevent many different types of attacks from reaching your application. This is probably what you are looking for, because it is a "drop in" solution requiring no modification to your application.

An input validation library will help, but you should keep in mind there is no silver bullet, you can't call one routine or install some software an expect all vulnerabilities will disappear. Input validation vulnerabilities are highly dependent how the data is used. For instance LFI, XSS, CRLF and SQL Injection all have different control characters and thus have their own requirements for filtering/escaping/encoding. If you want to build a truly solid PHP application then you have to read the [PHPSec LIbrary](http://phpsec.org/library/).

The best way to prevent SQL injection is using parameterized queries with a library like [PHP's PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html). This way you **KNOW** that the query is immune to SQL injection regardless of where the data came from.

Furthermore there are some vulnerabilities that have nothing to do with input validation. CSRF and crypto violations are both excellent examples. You should also read the [OWASP Top 10](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a special case, just always use parametrized queries when interacting with a database.

Because setting up parametrized queries with PHP/mysqli can be a verbose pain I'd highly recommend Rob Poyntz [Codesense_mysqi class](http://www.robpoyntz.com/blog/?p=189).  It's a neat little wrapper that hides most of the tedium.

Comment: sql injection isn't the only threat.

Comment: another threat is spamming to masses of bcc's cc's from your server